# How to sense a particular letter in user input in JS

Tags: javascript, html

If I type something with the letter 1 it should redirect to another page for eg: 1sometxt.
if not it should redirect to another page

```
function functionclick() {
     var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
     var input1 = "1";
     if (input === input1 + i dont know what to give here ) {
         window.open("www.example.com");
     }else {
window.open("www.example.com");
}
 }
```

Comment: You need to listen to the input event on the element, so that you can reference its most updated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("change"), (e)=>{

     var input = e.target.value
    
     if (input.includes(1) ) {
         window.open("www.example.com");
     }else {
         window.open("www.example.com");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `input` contain '1' by using `input.includes('1')`, or if '1' should be the first character the if condition could be something like this

```
if(input[0] === input1) { // doesn't matter what next characters are, check if input first character equal to input1 variable
  // your code here
}
```